# Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp-2

Estou quebrando a cabeça aqui a algum tempo e ainda não entendi o erro. Estou aprendendo sobre o CakePHP. Fiz o MVC da tabela Regionals manualmente, e, para os outros, usei o bake. O problema é que quando tento adicionar uma nova congregação, esse erro do título é retornado. Pesquisei em outros lugares, mas ainda não encontrei solução.

Controller CongregacaosController.php

```
/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator');

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Congregacao->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('congregacaos', $this->paginate());
    }

/**
 * view method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Congregacao->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid congregacao'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Congregacao.' . $this->Congregacao->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('congregacao', $this->Congregacao->find('first', $options));
    }

/**
 * add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Congregacao->create();
            if ($this->Congregacao->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The congregacao has been saved'), 'flash/success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The congregacao could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash/error');
            }
        }
        $regionals = $this->Congregacao->Regional->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('regionals'));
    }

/**
 * edit method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->Congregacao->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Congregacao->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid congregacao'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->Congregacao->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The congregacao has been saved'), 'flash/success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The congregacao could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash/error');
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Congregacao.' . $this->Congregacao->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->Congregacao->find('first', $options);
        }
        $regionals = $this->Congregacao->Regional->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('regionals'));
    }

/**
 * delete method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @throws MethodNotAllowedException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function delete($id = null) {
        if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        $this->Congregacao->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Congregacao->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid congregacao'));
        }
        if ($this->Congregacao->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Congregacao deleted'), 'flash/success');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Congregacao was not deleted'), 'flash/error');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Model Congregacao.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Congregacao Model
 *
 * @property Regionals $Regionals
 * @property Membro $Membro
 */
class Congregacao extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'nome' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'regionals_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Regionals' => array(
            'className' => 'Regionals',
            'foreignKey' => 'regionals_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Membro' => array(
            'className' => 'Membro',
            'foreignKey' => 'congregacao_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

Model Regional.php

```
    public $validate = array(
        'descricaoRegional' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
}
```

Controller RegionalsController.php

```
    public function index() 
    {
        $this->set('regionals', $this->Regional->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $this->Regional->regionals_id = $id;
        $this->set('regional', $this->regional->read());
    }

     public function add() 
     {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {
            if ($this->Regional->save($this->request->data)) 
            {
                //$this->Session->setFlash("A regional foi adicionada com sucesso");
                $this->Session->setFlash(__("A regional foi adicionada com sucesso."), 'flash_success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null) 
    {
        $this->Regional->id = $id;
        if ($this->request->is('get')) 
        {
            $this->request->data = $this->Regional->read();
        } 
        else
        {
            if ($this->Regional->save($this->request->data)) 
            {
                //$this->Session->setFlash("A regional $id foi atualizada.");
                $this->Session->setFlash(__("A regional $id foi atualizada."), 'flash_success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function delete($regionals_id) 
    {
        if (!$this->request->is('post')) 
        {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        if ($this->Regional->delete($regionals_id)) 
        {
            //$this->Session->setFlash("A regional $regionals_id foi deletada.");
            $this->Session->setFlash(__("A regional $regionals_id foi deletada."), 'flash_danger');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Grato a qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema.

No CongregacaosController.php, linha 58, está assim:

```
$regionals = $this->Congregacao->Regional->find('list');
```

Então consultei meu model Congregacao.php, e lá está assim, na linha 46:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Regionals' => array(
            'className' => 'Regionals',
            'foreignKey' => 'regionals_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

Ou seja, o correto é "Regionals", não "Regional". Foi só corrigir no controller e o add passou a funcionar normalmente.

```
$regionals = $this->Congregacao->Regionals->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array('id', 'descricao_regionals')
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria útil ter mais informações sobre o erro pra te apontar uma direção. Inicialmente você está tentando chamar um método de uma variável que não é um objeto...
Pra tentar te ajudar, se você estiver usando o apache, pense em ativar o mod xdebug, ele vai te dar mais informações sobre o erro.

**Xampp para windows:**

Adicione essas linhas no seu php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.cli_color = 1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

**No apache / linux:**

Instalação:

```
\# pecl install xdebug
```

Linhas a adicionar no php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.cli_color = 1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

**Mais informações sobre o xdebug:**

http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Posta aí o detalhamento do erro e vejo se consigo te ajudar mais.

Abraço

Comment: O xdebug já está ativado aqui. Essa mensagem "Call to a member..." é uma exceção pronta do CakePHP. Ele até tem um debug próprio, mas não sei usá-lo corretamente. O que mais posso postar para detalhar o erro?